# Show number of connections to a specific database

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to show on my website how many threads are established to the website db right now. Tried:

```
show status like 'Threads_connected'
```

The problem is it shows how many threads are established to the **entire** mysql server, not only to a **specific** (single) database. I need to show how many clients are connected to a specific db.

Comment: When I use `show processlist` then mysql returns 0 rows but when I use show status like 'Threads_connected' mysql returns hundreds. I am confuse :)

Comment: Duplicate?? The "answer" shows how many processes are established... processes are different from connections, right? Edited question, renamed connections with threads.